# VB.NET fails to read an Excel cell's Value

Tags: vb.net, excel, user-defined-functions

VB6 can open an Excel workbook and read a cell's Value, even if the cell contains a formula that uses a user-defined function; however, VB.NET 2012 always returns an error code (0x800A07ED) instead of the Value.  Does anyone know how to coax VB.NET into returning the cell's actual Value?

---

VB.NET fails when the cell's formula contains a UDF. For example, the cell's Formula can be `=MyFunction(A1)` (where MyFunction is a Public Function in a Public Module).

```
' A1's Value is "123".
' B1's Formula is "=MyFunction(A1)".
'
' After opening the workbook with VB.NET:
Dim rng1Cell As Excel.Range
rng1Cell = Sheet1.Range("B1")

Dim dblValue As Double
dblValue = CType(rng1Cell.Value, Double)

' dblValue now equals 0x800A07ED
```

Comment: does it return error code only on formula cell or on all the cells?

Comment: Please provide an example of the code you're using to read the cell's value. It will help others diagnose what might be going wrong.

Comment: VB.NET fails when the cell's formula contains a UDF.  For example, the cell's Formula can be "=MyFunction(A1)" (where MyFunction is a Public Function in a Public Module).

Comment: ' A1's Value is "123".
' B1's Formula is "=MyFunction(A1)".
'
' After opening the workbook with VB.NET:
'
Dim rng1Cell As Excel.Range
rng1Cell = Sheet1.Range("B1")    
Dim dblValue As Double
dblValue = CType(rng1Cell.Value, Double)
'
' dblValue now equals 0x800A07ED.